# how does the task-tracker gets the data for map task from another node if data is not-local?

Tags: hadoop

How does the task tracker gets its data for map task from another node in case if data is not-local?

Does it talk directly to the data node of the machine containing data directly or it talks to its own data node which in-turn talks to the other one?

Thanks,
Suresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task tracker itself doesn't get the data - it launches (or reuses) a JVM to run a Map task. The map task uses the DFS File System client to query the name node for the block locations of the file it is to process. The client then connects to the data node where one of the blocks is replicated to actually acquire the file contents (as a stream).

If you want to delve deeper, the source is an excellent place to get a good understanding - check out the DFSClient and inner class DFSInputStream (especially the bestNode method)

- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.2/src/hdfs/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSClient.java?view=markup

  - Class starts around line 1443
  - `openInfo()` method @ line 1494
  - `chooseDataNode()` method @ 1800

Comment: Thanks Chris. So the job tracker when assigning a task to a task tracker would just indicate the job id and the input split (does it have an id?) to be executed. It wont say where to find that split. It would be the responsibility of the map task to find it.And most likely it will find it in the same node (by contacting the name node) as thats how the Job scheduler mostly assigns the task. Is this understanding correct? I will take a look at the code. Can you also point to some books or online resources which discusses the internals?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Hadoop-Definitive-Guide-Tom-White/dp/1449311520/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1338602236&sr=1-1

Comment: The task assignment to task trackers is decided by the TaskScheduler.assignTasks method